# Font not displayed as expected, why aren't the top of my i's rounded?

Tags: html, css, font-face, webfonts

I am trying to get a custom font working, code as follows:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Biko';
  src: url('/fonts/Biko_Bold.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: bold;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Biko', Fallback, sans-serif;
}
```

This font displays like so:

[image]

However this is not correct, the top of the letter `i` should be rounded, this is what the font should look like (note this is a screenshot of the OTF preview):

[image]

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Not the same font obviously...look at the `s` ...for instance, clearly not the same.

Comment: The second screenshot is the preview of the OTF file though.

Comment: Doesn't matter...they clearly aren't the same...so there is something else going on.

Comment: So are you saying the way I have import it is incorrect or the otf preview I'm looking at in finder is lying to me?

Comment: No way to tell without a demo but it certainly *looks* like the font isn't loading.

Comment: As Paulie_D says, clearly the font isn't being used at all, it's not just the `i` — you should re-title your question to be along the lines of _why is my font not loading_ and try to provide a [mcve]

Comment: The font in your screenshot looks like some version of Helvetica